# How extend a parent class methods object literal return type?

Tags: typescript

Im extending a class with a `serialize` method.
It should do the same thing as its parent but append some keys.

```
export declare class Parent {
    serialize(): {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    };
}
```

```
export default class Child extends Parent {
    serialize() {
        return {
            ...super.serialize(),
            something: 'extra'
        };      
    }
}
```

I would like a extract a type for my extension - something like `SerializedChild`. Is it possible in this case and if so how can I do that?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/w62nvw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (so no dependencies on undeclared/third-party types unless your question hinges on them) .  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Is your question "why does my code XXX not throw warnings" or "how do I extract the type from YYY"?  While both questions relate to your code example, they don't really relate to each other; it's best for Stack Overflow questions to be usable as a FAQ.  That is, each post should ask a single question.  So, is your "I don't understand why my code does not throw warnings in the first place" merely an aside?  Or is it the main point of your question?  In either case, please consider modifying the question to only ask one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this

```
type SerializedChild = {
    // Manually readd properties from Parent.serialize
    x: number;
    y: number;
    // Add any "extensions"
    something: string
    
}

class Child extends Parent {
    serialize() : SerializedChild {
        return {
            ...super.serialize(),
            something: 'extra'
        };      
    }

    // ...
}
```